# AppSettings is not returning when calling Azure WebSiteManagementClient GetConfiguration

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

using the .NET Azure packages, I'm trying to read the AppSettings for an app service on my azure account.

When i attempt to get the site configuration, alot of the values are **null** including the AppSettings property

i'm using the following packages in my console app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.1.3-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites" version="1.6.0-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.5" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.4-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

The code below reads the configuration from the app service

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string subscriptionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSubscription"];
            string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenantId"];
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
            string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

            var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).Result;

            WebSiteManagementClient webClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(serviceCreds);
            webClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            string resourceGroup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceGroup"];
            string appServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppServiceName"];
            string location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppLocation"];

            SiteConfig siteConfig = webClient.WebApps.GetConfiguration(resourceGroup, appServiceName);

            IList<NameValuePair> appSettings = siteConfig.AppSettings;
            //appSettings is null, but shouldn't be
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

i know the credentials are correct because:

- The siteConfig returns some data that is correct in the portal
- I can update the application settings with the following code:

  ```
  var settings = new StringDictionary
  {
      Location = location,
      Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
              { "Key", "a value" },
      },
  };

  webClient.WebApps.UpdateApplicationSettings(resourceGroup, appServiceName, settings);
  ```

**Update**:

I decided to call the REST API directly. the same problem occurred:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

I'm not sure why the appsettings isnt being returned as part of GetConfiguration.

But there is an more [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_ListApplicationSettings) method that does work

```
StringDictionary appSettings = webClient.WebApps.ListApplicationSettings(resourceGroup, appServiceName);
```